# How to extract observations and dates for the months between march and july for different years?

Tags: r, date

I need to filter the rows for the months from march to july but how? Both variables "date" and "temp" for those months should remain.

```
date <- as.POSIXct(c('2006-01-10 13:01:22', '2006-02-11 12:13:11',
                   '2006-03-12 13:12:11', '2006-04-13 11:01:22',
                   '2006-05-14 15:13:11', '2006-06-15 13:12:11',
                   '2006-07-16 16:13:12', '2006-08-17 14:12:12',
                   '2006-09-10 13:01:22', '2006-10-11 12:13:11',
                   '2006-11-12 13:12:11', '2006-12-13 11:01:22',
                   '2007-01-10 13:01:22', '2007-02-11 12:13:11',
                   '2007-03-12 13:12:11', '2007-04-13 11:01:22',
                   '2007-05-14 15:13:11', '2007-06-15 13:12:11',
                   '2007-07-16 16:13:12', '2007-08-17 14:12:12',
                   '2007-09-10 13:01:22', '2007-10-11 12:13:11',
                   '2007-11-12 13:12:11', '2007-12-13 11:01:22'))

temp <- as.numeric(c("-2.8", "-1.2", "0", "1", "2.2",
                   "5.2", "2", "3", "5", "5",
                   "5.3", "2.3", "2.8", "2.9", "6.9",
                   "6.4", "8.9", "10.2", "6", "5.7",
                   "4.9", "4.2", "2.7", "1.3"))
             
temp <- data.frame(date, temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution with `lubridate` and `dplyr`

```
temp <- data.frame(date=ymd_hms(c('2006-01-10 13:01:22', '2006-02-11 12:13:11',
                          '2006-03-12 13:12:11', '2006-04-13 11:01:22',
                          '2006-05-14 15:13:11', '2006-06-15 13:12:11',
                          '2006-07-16 16:13:12', '2006-08-17 14:12:12',
                          '2006-09-10 13:01:22', '2006-10-11 12:13:11',
                          '2006-11-12 13:12:11', '2006-12-13 11:01:22',
                          '2007-01-10 13:01:22', '2007-02-11 12:13:11',
                          '2007-03-12 13:12:11', '2007-04-13 11:01:22',
                          '2007-05-14 15:13:11', '2007-06-15 13:12:11',
                          '2007-07-16 16:13:12', '2007-08-17 14:12:12',
                          '2007-09-10 13:01:22', '2007-10-11 12:13:11',
                          '2007-11-12 13:12:11', '2007-12-13 11:01:22')),
                  temp= as.numeric(c("-2.8", "-1.2", "0", "1", "2.2",
                           "5.2", "2", "3", "5", "5",
                           "5.3", "2.3", "2.8", "2.9", "6.9",
                           "6.4", "8.9", "10.2", "6", "5.7",
                           "4.9", "4.2", "2.7", "1.3")))
 
 temp1 <- temp %>% 
   filter(month(date) > 2 & month(date) < 8)
```

Result

```
1  2006-03-12 13:12:11  0.0
2  2006-04-13 11:01:22  1.0
3  2006-05-14 15:13:11  2.2
4  2006-06-15 13:12:11  5.2
5  2006-07-16 16:13:12  2.0
6  2007-03-12 13:12:11  6.9
7  2007-04-13 11:01:22  6.4
8  2007-05-14 15:13:11  8.9
9  2007-06-15 13:12:11 10.2
10 2007-07-16 16:13:12  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` with `%m` to extract the month from `date` and use it to subset for *the months from march to july*:

```
i <- as.integer(format(temp$date, "%m"))
temp[i>2 & i<8,]
#                  date temp
#3  2006-03-12 13:12:11  0.0
#4  2006-04-13 11:01:22  1.0
#5  2006-05-14 15:13:11  2.2
#6  2006-06-15 13:12:11  5.2
#7  2006-07-16 16:13:12  2.0
#15 2007-03-12 13:12:11  6.9
#16 2007-04-13 11:01:22  6.4
#17 2007-05-14 15:13:11  8.9
#18 2007-06-15 13:12:11 10.2
#19 2007-07-16 16:13:12  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp[month(date) %between% c(3,7),]
```